# Lookup route from URL in Ember router

Tags: ember.js

The Ember router creates a URL from a route, e.g. with the link-to helper. Is it possible to reverse-lookup a route from a given URL?

The reason for this is that I have some absolute URL links in my database which point to pages in my Ember app, and I want to transition to them within the app. Using `<a href={{link}}>` works, but breaks my tests (when running `ember test -s`) as following the link redirects the whole browser page, stopping the test suite. If it's possible to redirect to an absolute URL without breaking the test suite that would also do the trick.

Comment: I removed my answer since it's not answering your question at all...Now I am also interested for this solution. `Is it possible to reverse-lookup a route from a given URL`